# Fotorama zoom functionality add for child product images of group product : M2

Tags: magento2, image, grouped-products, zoom, fotorama

I want to add fotorama zoom functionality for child product images of group product at product details page.

i have update this ("Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml") file, so now using magento2 script i got child images for group product.

can any one guide me for this functionality.

I have try using this script but it's not working.

```
require([
        'jquery','jquery/ui',
        'fotorama/fotorama'
    ], function ($, fotorama) {
        'use strict';


    $('.fotorama').fotorama({
      width: 700,
      maxwidth: '100%',
      ratio: 16/9,
      allowfullscreen: true,
      nav: 'thumbs'
    });
});
```

thanks.